# animating views when orientation changes not working

Tags: ios, swift, orientation-changes

I have a view controller that i want to animate my views position when orientation changes.

i have some views set in storyboard and some added in the ViewControllers viewDidLoad.

I'm overriding

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({context in

        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);

        }, completion: nil)


}
```

the size changes but not in an animation.

I also have a button that is set in storyboard with autolayout.
And it also moves according to its constraints but the change is not animated.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Its probably because there's already an animation running, so your custom animation is not executed, u may have to override the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: What do you mean, custom animation? this is regular UIView animation.